# Kibana - How to manage legend in pie charts

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm new on Kibana.
I've created custom Visualization using pie chart.

In legend i've 2 values: 0 and 1
But i want to display F instead of 0 and T instead of 1 and i don't know how to do this.

I found in Visualization edition a field named uiStateJson. I think we could manage legend name in this field but i dont found any doc on kibana. Maybe i'm wrong :|

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to re-ingest the data and set 0 to `F` and 1 to `T`.

Your other option is to create a scripted field to convert the values `0` and `1` into `F` and `T` but scripted fields can have performance implications for large data sets. In Kibana 5, Management-> Index Patterns. Select target Index Pattern. Select the "scripted fields" tab and create a scripted field that will convert to the desired format.